# Stackoverflow error in getConfig()

Tags: java, android

I have a custom view that is manually drawn,to make blur image I got this error frequently in my application the code used

```
Bitmap bitmap = sentBitmap.copy(sentBitmap.getConfig(), true);
```

this error is:-

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.getConfig(Bitmap.java:841)
       at android.view.GLES20Canvas.setupModifiers(GLES20Canvas.java:1119)
       at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java:715)
       at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:117)
       at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:393)
       at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:892)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11252)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10691)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:5727)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:5005)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10689)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:5727)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:5005)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10689)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:5727)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:5005)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11255)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10691)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:5727)
```

Comment: That's happening because of recursion of some kind, show your code for  onDraw

Comment: i am not using onDraw(), in this i am try to make image blur and fixed it in to window size.for that i amtrying to change pixel of the bitmap image

Comment: You said you have `custom view` and you must have override `onDraw` ?

Comment: Sry for that, my intention to make the image as blur